# Got unauthorized error when renaming mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongohq

I am using mongohq sandbox plan. In the command prompt,

```
db["oldCollectionName"].renameCollection("newCollectionName", true)
```

works fine without using admin database.

However, I got "unauthorized" exception when I do this in Java:

```
oldCollection.rename(newCollectionName);
```

Since I am using mongohq sandbox plan, I don't have access to admin database. Is there a way to rename this collection without creating a new collection, copying over all the documents, and dropping the old collection?

Comment: I hope you would not do that often. In that case why not rename the data model with annotation @Document(collection = "NAME_OF_YOUR_NEW_COLLECTION"). This should take care of renaming the collection.

Comment: I need to be able to do it with java code because this comes from user actions dynamically. Therefore, using annotation may not help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java and using Jongo you can do the following:

```
MongoCollection col = new Jongo(DbConfigurer.getDB()).getCollection("CODE");
col.getDBCollection().rename("CODE45", true);
```

I've just tested and it works.

Now using the 'runCommand' (same than using db.command) in the following example:

```
DB db = ....getDB();
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);
jongo.runCommand("{ renameCollection : 'OLD_NAME', to: 'NEW_NAME', dropTarget: true}");
```

I obtain the same error you have.

I read from some documentation you have to connect first to admin database to process some of the command not allowed, so i did the same but with "admin" db, and i obtain the following error stack:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , 
"errmsg" : "exception: invalid collection name: NEW_NAME" , "code" : 15967 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Strange to have such different behaviors...